# Is there an equivalent to XML::DOM::Node::dispose in XML::LibXML?

Tags: perl, xmldom, xml-libxml, xml

Does there exist an equivalent for the method `dispose` of `XML::DOM` in XML::LibXML?

I have to parse many XML files and I don't want to have memory problems.

Comment: There should be no need to explicitly dispose of your XML document. Have you tried it? There's no point in fixing imaginary problems

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for `XML::LibXML` but [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm#) definitely has a `purge` method. This is useful for large XML documents so you can discard 'processed' data that you may have already handled.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

sub print_and_purge {
   my ( $twig, $element ) = @_; 
    ##do something with this element

   print "-----\n";
   $element -> print;
   print "-----\n";

   $twig -> purge; 
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( 'twig_handlers' => { 'element' => \&print_and_purge },
                              'pretty_print' => 'indented' ); 

 $twig -> parse ( \*DATA );

 __DATA__
 <root>
     <element>fish</element>
     <element>
        <subelement>content</subelement>
     </element>
     <element/>
 </root>
```

Note - this is an illustrative example - it's not a particularly useful thing to do, because you're printing the 'elements' and discarding the 'root'. But it's more useful if you're extracting information from your XML.

Also of interest is the [`flush`](http://search.cpan.org/~mirod/XML-Twig-3.49/Twig.pm#Flush) method, which is probably more relevant if you're doing the above:

> Flushes a twig up to (and including) the current element, then deletes all unnecessary elements from the tree that's kept in memory. flush keeps track of which elements need to be open/closed, so if you flush from handlers you don't have to worry about anything. Just keep flushing the twig every time you're done with a sub-tree and it will come out well-formed. After the whole parsing don't forget toflush one more time to print the end of the document. The doctype and entity declarations are also printed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no mechanism to explicitly release memory because it automatically happens as soon as possible. Resources are automatically freed as references to them are relinquished. Use properly-scoped variables, and you'll be ok.

---

If you actually do want to trim a document tree (though I don't see why), you can use the following to remove a node from the tree:

```
$node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
```

The node (and its children) will be freed when the last reference to it goes away. Usually, this is as soon as `$node` goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `$node->unbindNode` and drop all references to the node *and any of its children, child attributes, etc*. Then the internal `xmlNode` will be destroyed.